# Unable to login to a test site using JMeter

Tags: jmeter, performance, load-testing

I am new to JMeter.I have checked few posts related to this but no luck.

I am trying to login to my web application using JMter. For that, I have configured two HTTP sampler under one thread group. One is to get the login page another is to put parameters. when I run the test plan it does not response homepage. But in View Result Tree "sampler result" tab it shows Response code:200.

It works when I record using **HTTP(S) Script Test Recorder**. But when I run the same script it does not work.

Note: 
Did not try Blazemeter chrome extension because application under test works only in Internet Explorer. And tried to play Badboy(Testing software) script, does not work.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you simply don't have [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-load-testing-scenarios-jmeter-part-1-correlations) in place, modern web applications widely use dynamic parameters for storing client state, security reasons, etc. so I believe your test should look like:

- HTTP Get request to Login Page (mimic opening the page in browser)

  - Extract any dynamic parameters
- HTTP POST request to Login Page (mimic filling all the required fields and hitting "Login" button)

You can just record your test one more time to see what parameters differ, once you figure it out you can use [JMeter's Post-Processors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) in order to extract them from the first response and add to the second request.

Comment: I have debug web application using fidler. And I found that there are two hidden parameters: ViewState and EventValidation. Then i used Regular Expression Extractor for  for these two parameters. But in the response data tab of View Result Tree, i am getting below error.   "The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
"

Comment: Here's my jmeter test plan pictures: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3xVXtcwNaUfTVdWT05FSlVzQ2M/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3xVXtcwNaUfeGdfek9RcTc1czg/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3xVXtcwNaUfQlJycExGQnZ3NDg/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3xVXtcwNaUfQXU0X2tVWVhUck0/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3xVXtcwNaUfcWpHaVVoeXRCOVk/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3xVXtcwNaUfem5wSVBHb1NEU2M/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The error is about incorrect VIEWSTATE parameter (I don't think it should include the trailing quotation mark), double check your regular expression.. In general [parsing HTML with regular expressions isn't the brightest idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748), consider using [CSS/JQuery Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-cssjquery-extractor-jmeter) instead.

Comment: I solved previous error by checking "Encode" checkbox in login POST page.Then I tried using both regex extractor and CSS/JQuery Extractor. For both i am getting same results. For GET request it shows the login page in Response Data tab and for POST it shows the same login page with error message "Error Occured! Please contact to administrator". Though i have given correct username and password.

Comment: My JMeter test plans look like: 

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3xVXtcwNaUfcHFrVU5qQnZFRzQ/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3xVXtcwNaUfblBoVlFHaFkzU0U/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3xVXtcwNaUfMFBMVFBfcWRPclk/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3xVXtcwNaUfRk9hS28xTC1zRHc/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3xVXtcwNaUfN1hycVRzUUk4dVk/view?usp=sharing